# nth-child in nested divs

Tags: css

I am attempting to hide the last 3 divs with the class name `.latest-item` using `nth-child`:

```
<div class="latest-group">

            <div class="latest-1 latest-item latest-sort-1">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
            </div><!--end latest-1-->

            <div class="latest-2 latest-item latest-sort-2">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
            </div><!--end latest-2-->

            <div class="latest-3 latest-item latest-sort-3">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
            </div><!--end latest-3-->

          </div><!--end latest-group-->

          <div class="latest-group">

            <div class="latest-4 latest-item latest-sort-1">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
            </div><!--end latest-4-->

            <div class="latest-5 latest-item latest-sort-2">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
            </div><!--end latest-5-->

            <div class="latest-6 latest-item latest-sort-3">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Paragraph</p>
            </div><!--end latest-6-->

          </div><!--end latest-group-->​
```

and the CSS:

```
.latest-item:nth-child(n+3) { 
           display:none;
       }​
```

I can not correctly target the divs with the class name `.latest-item` . In jQuery I could do something like:

> $(".latest-item").slice(3).hide();

Here's a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nMbm5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is a shortcoming in CSS for the moment. Using javascript instead:

```
$(".latest-item").slice(3).hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [`nth-last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo) and [`last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo) instead: http://jsfiddle.net/nMbm5/1/

Comment: it won't work if the 3 `.latest-item` span across different `.latest-group` though..

Comment: @zen So in this case, to get it to span across 3 different `.latest-group` divs, I will need to go with a js solution?

Comment: @Yahreen for quick answer yes you should use js..because when you use this code below, it'll choose the last 2 `.latest-item` from different `.latest-group`. I don't know if this is a bug in CSS3 or not..

.latest-item:nth-last-child(-n+2){
background: red;            
}